# Prime checking and factorization with just bit cheking

Tags: primes, factoring, bit-manipulation

I've read about some methods of prime factorization like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631559/algorithms-for-finding-the-prime-factorization-of-an-integer) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/). However, I'm wondering: what can we do in prime factorization with just some bit manipulation and without other variables/constants?

In base 10, we can get some hints about the factors of an integer just be checking the digits:

- digit's place is even --> int is even
- digit's place is 0 of 5 --> int is divisible by 5
- sum_of_digit % 3 = int % 3
- sum_of_digit % 9 = int % 9

Given an integer `num` as a bit array, how can we check for `num`'s primality and guess or extract its prime factors just by looking at its bits like we do with digits in base 10?

```
   There are 5 0's --> (num % (2^5)) = 0
            / \
           /   \
           |   |  
1010101110100000
      | |      ^
      | |      | last bit is 0 --> num is even
      | |
       v
may be these 3 bits can give some information?
```

What's allowed:

- bit-manipulations which take 1 argument are allow. This includes functions like `not` but not `xor`.
- `if`s and loops are allowed but bits in `num` will be used for the flag. (no using `if num > 2`)
- `num` is the only variable/constant allowed to be declared. We can `not(num)` (flip every bits in `num`) but not `num - 2` (`2` is another var/const).
- Operating on bits only in `num` like summing all the bits (`bit_sum(20) = bit_sum(b1010) = 2` because there are 2 `1`s)

Bonus if the operation can quickly be done by hand like the given examples for base 10.

Answer (score 3):

Given any specific candidate divisor $d$, it is easy to check whether $d$ is a divisor of the number (the standard modular reduction algorithm is a generalization of those tricks you mentioned).  This can be done for all $d$.  However, it doesn't help with efficient factorization, because there are exponentially many candidate divisors, so trying each one, one-by-one, is far too inefficient.

In other words, this approach to factorization is not likely to be useful, no matter how many tricks you accumulate.

Comment: I'm not really looking for efficiency here. I'm just thinking about "What can I do with just bit manipulation?" and "How much information can I get from just a single bit field?"

Comment: @JohnZhau, modular reduction is a form of bit manipulation, so I don't think there is any principled line one can draw between checking (say) divisibility by 3 vs divisibility by any other number.  Of course divisibility by values of the form $2^k \pm 1$ are particularly easy, but one can also come up with more complex tricks for more complex divisors; ultimately the limit of that progression is that you end up re-inventing modular reduction.

Comment: Can such divisibility be done just from staring at the binary of the given number and without doing some operations like ```and```, ```or```, ```xor``` with the binary of ```3```? I'm looking to extract data just from looking at the bit field and without the given binary doing anything like another number/binary.

Comment: @JohnZhau, depends on who is doing the staring and their mental abilities.  (The same could be said about the sum of digits modulo 9.)  I don't think there is a clear line you can draw anywhere here.

Comment: "Staring" is just an over-simplified example of things humans do. I'm thinking of using only operations that take in only 1 argument to extract information. "Is this a ```1```?" and ```not``` are such operations.

Comment: @JohnZhau, if you want to make this a well-defined question about computer science, I think you need to clearly specify a model of computation that describes what the algorithm is and is not allowed to do -- e.g., 'only allowed to read each bit of the input once', 'must take linear time', 'must be a DFA with a constant number of states', something like that.    "using only operations that take in only 1 argument" isn't precise enough for me (are loops allowed?  are conditionals allowed? etc.)